# AppendTo elimina el div original

Tags: javascript, html

tengo este fragmento de código js

```
window.onload = function() {
  $( ".similar" ).appendTo( "#alerta_adicionar" );
};
```

me clona un div ya existente dentro de un modal y funciona, pero me borra la sección donde estaba antes y la idea es que permanezcan ambos

ejemplo

asi es como esta el html

```
<div class="similar">(un div cualquiera)
<div id="alerta_adicionar">(este es el modal)
```

entonces lo que hago es meter a .similar dentro de #alerta_adicionar

y asi es como queda en el modal

```
<div id="alerta_adicionar">
  <div class="similar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que no estás clonando, solo estás moviendo el elemento, debes usar la función `clone` de la siguiente manera:

```js
$( ".similar" ).clone().appendTo( "#alerta_adicionar" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="similar">Este div será clonado</div>

<div id="alerta_adicionar">
</div>
```

Te dejo un link a la documentación por si la necesitas: https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: mas claro no puede ser

Comment: jajajaja que bueno que quedó claro, saludos compañero :D.